# Redirect the people from website join the telegram group

Tags: php, api, telegram-bot

Is it possible to create a PHP script which allows us to redirect the people from website form to join telegram group?

Example, we have a simple form on the website with username and email. when user will fill the form the user will redirect from website to join the telegram group.

Does somebody know how to?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
header('Location: <telegram url>');
```